# convert int counter to char in for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, casting, counter

I can't seem to find an answer as to why **I am not able to type cast a counting integer into a char type within a for loop**. Below is a simple instance in which I have tried to declare the type case before and after the loop begins but have not gotten any where. Fundamentally, I don't understand why this is not allowed and can't, or am too stupid to find any information on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void){
    int i;                
    //char j;         <-If i declare here
    //char j=(char)i; <-or here there is no profound affect 

    for(i=0;i<9;++i){
        char j=(char)i;
        printf("i=%d, j=%c\n", i, j);} <--Case A: j=%c, Case B: j=%d 
  return 0;
}

OUTPUT

Case A Output printf("%c",j) (j initialized as char & typecast as char)
i=0, j=
i=1, j=
i=2, j=
i=3, j=
i=4, j=
i=5, j=
i=6, j=
i=7, j=
i=8, j=

Case B Output printf("%d",j) (j initialized as char & typecast as char)
i=0, j=0
i=1, j=1 <- if typecast from int to char worked these values should not  
i=2, j=2 <- show up when using printf("%d",j)
i=3, j=3
i=4, j=4
i=5, j=5
i=6, j=6 
i=7, j=7
i=8, j=8
```

I was expecting a printed value of the the number as a char instead of blank values. There could be an issue with terminal or ascii values not being represented properly, but that does not answer the root of my question. ** Case B shows numeric values for the j column. However, these values were printed as using a double place holder. If my type case from double to char had worked, these values would be either the associated ascii values for the numbers or garbage.** I'm not looking for a way around this, just to understand what is going on when the code is compiled or in runtime. Thanks!

Comment: What you mean by "not able"? Is there a warning from the compiler? An error? Does it misbehave in some way? Part of a [MCVE] is the input, expected output, and actual output; saying "doesn't work" or words to that effect is not helpful. Are you expecting the result to be a printable character? [The ASCII values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_groups) from 0-8 aren't printable (bell and backspace are the closest you get), so you wouldn't see much of use in the terminal.

Comment: local vars are not initialized, so with the current code, the value of i can be anything. And yeah, you really need to explain what is your expectation and the actual result.

Comment: If you want to see the integer values held by `j`, print with `printf("i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j);`. As @ShadowRanger said, you won't see anything with `%c` for small values, because these characters are unprintable.

Comment: @khachik: `i` is the loop variable, and gets initialized to `0` at the beginning of the `for` loop. No undefined behavior there.

Answer (score 0):

The Terminal has maybe a problem with the NUL character when displayed with %c in the formated string. I changed the Program a bit..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
int i, x=123456789;
//char j;
char j=(char)i;
printf("int i: %d\n",i);
printf("int x: %d\n",x);
printf("char j: %d\n",j);
printf("hex j: 0x%02x\n",j);
for(i=32;i<128;++i){
    char j=(char)i;
    printf("i=%d, j=0x%02x, j= %d, j =%c\n", i, j, j, j);
}
printf("char j: %c\n",j);
// Problems is the output as char?
// Programmers Notepad Consol Specific!
printf("Terminal Stops before this in PN :D\n");
return 0;
}
```

I think the Program does what you want when printing with %d or %x. But %c makes problems.
I used Programmers Notepad. Other Programs may not have my problem :D
Importand is that Printable characters start at decimal 32 with space. See [ASCII Printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Before that it is normal to get no output. %c tries to convert the decimal value in a printable character according to the ASCII table. Also have a look on the [C reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).The %d is for signed decimal Integer.

Answer (score -2):

Because the number you are trying to convert is bigger than a char. Char can only be 1 character, hence you can't fit 9 digits/characters into a single char. This would need to be a char[]/string to do what you are trying.

Or try changing x=0->9 but not more than a single digit.

Comment: The number being converted is between 0 and 8, which fits in every `char` that exists. `x` isn't being *used* anywhere.

Comment: `(char)7` is not `'7'` if you meant that.

Comment: Yea, sorry I should of left out var x and its values. I was going going to extend the code to using the i value to pull each of the 9 "char numbers" (1,2...8,9) in then sum them but decided the simpler the better.